# i want a URL rewriting for my URL using only .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

My URL is

```
http://127.0.0.1/public_html/organisation/home/index.php?page=Your-Profile
```

but i want my url looks like this using .htaccess only:-

```
 http://127.0.0.1/public_html/organisation/home/Your-Profile
```

i want to remove using .htaccess file `index.php?page=`

Please Help Me..

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `/index.php` as this is assumed/set by default by the engine, but you can't remove the `?page=` as this is a query parameter, not part of the 'url' as you are thinking it. So it would look like `http://127.0.0.1/public_html/organisation/home?page=Your-Profile`

If you're using wordpress then there is an option in admin to set 'pretty urls' which would achieve this through other means.

Comment: With `.htaccess` you can remove the query strings as well by redirecting them to a new url